# JAX-RS hide field just in specific methods

Tags: rest, jpa, jax-rs

I have a customer resource with a password which should not be transferred if I GET the user. That's why I annotated the getPassword method with the XmlTransient annotation. But when I PUT the password is null. Here it should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the XmlTransient annotation, and before you send the password in the GET action, edit it like:

```
user.setPassword("********");
```

or null, or any other value.

Just do it outside your transaction, or you will update it in database.